# Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let All = mongoose.Schema({
  school:{
      name:{
        type: String,
      },
      program:[{
        name: String,
        semester: Number,
        subject: [{name: String, crh: Number}]
      }]
  }
})

let allSub = module.exports = mongoose.model('allSub', All);
```

Mongoose collection i created

```
if(!course){
      let x = new All();
      x.school.name = School;
      x.school.program.name = Course;
      x.school.program.semester = Semester;
      x.school.program.subject.name = "One";
      x.save((err) =>{
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("Date saved");
        res.render('addinsub');
      })
    }
```

Data insertion block. It's giving me an error say that the x.school.program.subject.name of undefined.
How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the object first.

```
const x = new All();
x.school = {
    name: Course,
    program: [{
        semester: Semester,
        subject: {
            name: "one"
        }
    }]
};
x.save((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Date saved");
    res.render('addinsub');
})
```

Comment: Thanks bro, saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You need x.school.program.subject to be a object.

```
if(!course){
  let x = new All();
  x.school.name = School;
  x.school.program.name = Course;
  x.school.program.semester = Semester;
  x.school.program.subject = {name: "One"};
  x.save((err) =>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Date saved");
    res.render('addinsub');
  })
}
```